# Generating JSON Query Result in Codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, json, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

So i have database table named usermeta and have table structure like this :

```
-----------------------------------------------------------
| ummeta_id | user_id | meta_key    | meta_value          |
-----------------------------------------------------------
| 1         | 1       | fullname    | John Doe            |
| 2         | 1       | birthplace  | New York            |
| 3         | 1       | birthdate   | 1990/01/01          |
| 4         | 1       | mobile      | 0812-3456-7890      |
| 5         | 1       | email       | john.doe@mail.com   |
| 6         | 2       | fullname    | Jon Wick            |
| 7         | 2       | birthplace  | Washington DC       |
| 8         | 2       | birthdate   | 1985/10/21          |
| 9         | 2       | mobile      | 0890-1234-5678      |
| 10        | 2       | email       | wickjohn@mail.com   |
```

And i try to generate json data for all data from this database using Codeigniter (v 3.1.9) using Controller and Model.

This is my **Model** (model name: db_usermeta)

```
function userslist()
{
   $query = $this->db->select('*')
                     ->from('usermeta')
                     ->get();
   return $query->result();
}
```

This is my **Controller**

```
public function userlist()
{
   header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
   $query = $this->db_usermeta->userslist();
   $json_data = array();
   foreach ($query as $key)
   {
      $json_data[$key->meta_key] = $key->meta_value;
   }
   echo json_encode($json_data);
}
```

The result when i open using my browser to check the json data using web developer tool is only show last record, in this case only show data from user_id 2, like this:

```
{
  "fullname":"John Wick",
  "birthplace":"Washinton DC",
  "birthdate":"1985/10/21",
  "mobile":"0890-1234-5678",
  "email":"wickjohn@mail.com"
}
```

What I want to achieve is to show all json data nested like this:

```
"data": [
  {
    "fullname":"John Doe",
    "birthplace":"New York",
    "birthdate":"1990/01/01",
    "mobile":"0812-3456-7890",
    "email":"john.doe@mail.com"
  },
  {
    "fullname":"John Wick",
    "birthplace":"Washinton DC",
    "birthdate":"1985/10/21",
    "mobile":"0890-1234-5678",
    "email":"wickjohn@mail.com"
  }
]
```

How can i achieve this? Did I make a mistake on my controller and model. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `$key->meta_key` is overwriting for every record. that's why only last record appeared. You don't actually need to loop through to get json data.

```
public function userlist()
{
   header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
   $query = $this->db_usermeta->userslist();
   $json_data = array(array());
   $user_id_map = array();
   $index = 0;
   foreach ($query as $key)
   {
        if(!isset($user_id_map[$key->user_id])){
            $user_id_map[$key->user_id] = $index++;
        }
        $currentIndex = $user_id_map[$key->user_id];
        $json_data[$currentIndex][$key->meta_key] = $key->meta_value;
   }
   echo json_encode($json_data);
}
```

just change your **controller** code to this and this will return json data.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion. But the result is not as I expected. The JSON data show separatelly based from umeta_id.

Comment: @SigitDRedHat try the edited answer and let me know if that helps.

Comment: Wow! thank you very much Sir. Your code really work well and and really helped me...

Answer (score 0):

Since the meta key `fullname` is same for both records, you need to change the key name to something unique

```
foreach ($query as $key)
   {
      $json_data[$key->meta_key] = $key->meta_value;
   }
```

Change `$json_data[$key->meta_key]` to `$json_data[$key->meta_key.$key->user_id]`
or simply change it to `$json_data[$key->ummeta_id]`